# Pass data through segue to SWRevealController

Tags: xcode, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm making an app and it has a simple login page that for now will just a send a String (username) to the next screen. The next screen however uses an SWRevealViewController (https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController).

I've tried

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! MenuController
    vc.userType = userID.text
    }
```

But that gives me the error `Could not cast value of type 'SWRevealViewController' to 'MenuController'.` MenuController is the class I am trying to pass the data to.

I know this isn't a common Controller but hopefully somebody can help.

Comment: Based on your info I am presuming that destinationViewController is the SWRevealViewController, Right? If so then probably the MenuController is a property of the SWRevealViewController (revealViewController). If so then you have to cast the destinationViewController to SWRevealViewController and then access the revealViewController property as MenuController.

Comment: you can save `username` in `NSUserDefaults` to use it later, after loggin in.

Comment: @iRiziya I have that for now but that doesn't seem like the best solution

Comment: Hello, how did you solved this problem of passing data from view controller to a reveal view controller..

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let revealVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SWRevealViewController {
        if let menuVC = revealVC.revealViewController as? MenuController {
            menuVC.userType = userID.text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives me the error `cast from ()->SWRevealController! to unrelated type MenuController always fails`

Comment: Where does your MenuController lie in the view controller hierarchy? Is it the rearViewController of the SWRevealController instance?

Comment: I have a login page that segues to just a blank activity thats class is SWRevealController and that has a segue `sw_rear` that goes to MenuController

Comment: In this case its better to derive from SWRevealViewController and add properties that you want to pass to the menu controller within the SWRevalViewController. I don't think you can pass data to the menu controller without instantiating it. You could use globals and then access it from MenuController but that's not a good approach. Deriving is a better option since you can add custom properties to this.

Comment: Could you explain how I could go about doing that?

Comment: Is it possible to upload your project somewhere?